# why am I seeing output in python console from writing to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I was writing a python dictionary `book1` as a csv to a file in another folder. I generally use PyCharm, but today I decided to go with th python shell for some reason.
My code was this:

```
with open(filepath, 'w+') as file:
    for key in book1.keys():
        file.write('%s,%s\n'%(key, book1[key]))
```

and the code worked as expected, with all the right data in the right places,
except in the console, it printed this seemingly random sequence of numbers:
`73,88,98,89,86,86,90,92,102,94,92,104,92,90,94,94,88,86,90,90,88,88,113,103,109,107,105,106,73`

I have been using Python for some time, but I have only ever seen this for the first time, and i am not sure what i am looking at. [Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVudw.png)

Could Someone please enlighten me as to what those numbers might mean and why they never appeared in PyCharm?

Comment: The write method returns the number of bytes written.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's interesting. but I have used the write method in pycharm before and I dont remember that happening.

Comment: @LokeshChandak https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html says `f.write(string)` writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written; where f is the file object.

Comment: @yabhishek is correct - it's characters not bytes (I was reading the docs for binary IO).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between python script output and python console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822117/difference-between-python-script-output-and-python-console-output)

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info on this here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written.

>>> f.write('This is a test\n')
15